# Select query paginated without duplicates with bridge table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table **news**, a table **category** and a table **bridge**.

I want to select news with category ID = 1 or 2 or 3.

Example:

```
SELECT *
FROM NEWS
  INNER JOIN BRIDGE ON NEWS.ID = BRIDGE.ID_NEWS
WHERE BRIDGE.ID_CATEGORY IN (1,2,3)
```

Problem is that when i do a select i have the second news (NEWS.ID = 2) duplicated.

I can't use distinct and anyway distinct not resolve the problem when i use pagination.

SCENARIO:

TABLE `NEWS`

```
|ID|TITLE|
|1 |First new|
|2 |second new|
|3 |third new|
```

TABLE `CATEGORY`

```
|ID|TITLE|
|1 |Great|
|2 |Bad  |
|3 |Green|
```

TABLE `BRIDGE`

```
|ID_NEWS|ID_CATEGORY|
|1      |1
|2      |1
|2      |2
|3      |3
```

Results are:

```
First new, second new, second new, third new.
```

I want:

```
First new, second new, third new.
```

How can I have no duplicates?

Comment: Sample data is great, but you also need to specify the expected result.

Comment: I edited the post with expected results and i changed the query. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want all the columns from NEWS table, you could use:

```
SELECT n.ID,
       n.TITLE
FROM NEWS n
INNER JOIN BRIDGE b ON n.ID = b.ID_NEWS
WHERE b.ID_CATEGORY IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY n.ID,n.TITLE
```

`GROUP BY n.ID,n.TITLE` will take care of duplicates.

Another option would be using distinct if you want only NEWS.TITLE unique values for the specified categories.

```
SELECT distinct n.TITLE
FROM NEWS n
INNER JOIN BRIDGE b ON n.ID = b.ID_NEWS
WHERE b.ID_CATEGORY IN (1,2,3)
```

If you want all columns from `NEWS`  and `BRIDGE` and still want distinct result on NEWS.TITLE , you have to apply an aggregate function, for example min or max on BRIDGE.ID_CATEGORY to select only one row per TITLE.

Try:

```
SELECT n.ID,
       n.TITLE,
       max(b.ID_CATEGORY) as max_ID_CATEGORY
FROM NEWS n
INNER JOIN BRIDGE b ON n.ID = b.ID_NEWS
WHERE b.ID_CATEGORY IN (1,2,3)
GROUP BY n.ID,n.TITLE
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=afa8fc969636dbe7b7421c51db20cc75

Comment: Group by result is exactly what i want. Thank you.